# How can you more deeply research B&Bs and resorts in Canada?

Tags: canada, accommodation

This question generalises [this](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/57478/13759), where I already stated concerns about the corruptibility of websites like Tripadvisor. I narrow this question by focusing on Canada and assume the following:

1. The lodging does not belong to easily recognisable hotel chains.
2. Guide books do not cover the region in question.

Instead of questioning here for every region, how can a traveller find more objective criticism and reviews? Do the official provincial travel agencies endorse or review certain lodgings?

Comment: You could look at the FOBBA and/or BBCanada web sites, they are B&B associations, maybe you can find what you are looking for.

Comment: I am aware (because I have walked/biked past them and read their signs) of several Kawartha Lakes B&Bs that do not have their own websites, are not on TripAdvisor, but are on BBCanada. While you may or may not find objective reviews there, it seems to be one of the few places you can even find names and phone numbers.

Answer (score 1):

To find places, I've had success with finding places via http://www.bbcanada.com. Despite the "90s" look of the website, the information does seem to be accurate, up-to-date, and with more smaller places listed than anywhere else I've looked.

To find objective reviews, given the small size of B&Bs and their low volume of business compared to traditional hotels, I doubt there is a centralized objective source - you'll have to look at several things, such as:

- The CAA has lists of recommended hotels (e.g. see http://www.caasco.com/Auto/Road-Trip ), it may include some smaller places
- Sites like bbcanada.com have some reviews, but they tend to be biased to the positive side ("testimonials" from happy customers, not reviews)
- Booking.com reviews
- Some places may even have ratings on Yelp, Google+, etc.
- Perhaps local chambers of commerce, city hall websites, tourism board websites, etc have recommendations?

Also, hotels/B&Bs that have a highway sign (see http://www.mtc.gov.on.ca/en/tourism/tods.shtml ) must meet certain quality standards before being allowed a sign, so this may be an indication as well. However, as far as I know these criteria have more to do with "playing well within the tourism industry" than your actual guest experience.